# circuitikz: Controlling the size of poles

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc] {};
                    \node (c) at (1.5,0) [ocirc] {};
                    \node (b) at (3,0) [ocirc] {};
                    \node (d) at (1.5,2) [ocirc] {};
                    \node (e) at (1.5,-2)[ocirc] {};
                    
                    \node[left] at (a) {$a$};
                    \node[left] at (c) {$c$};
                    \node[right] at (b) {$b$};
                    \node[above] at (d) {$1$};
                    \node[below] at (e) {$0$};
                    
                    \path 
                    (a) edge           (d)
                    edge           (e)
                    (b) edge           (d)
                    edge           (e)
                    (d) edge           (c)
                    (c) edge           (e); 
                    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I control the size of the poles at `a,b,c,1,0`? I want to increase the radii of the poles.

Comment: You could just use a `circle` node and set [minimum width=...] or simply [inner sep=...].

Comment: I approve @JohnKormylo suggestion: using `circuitikz` for this diagram is a bit unnatural. There are several graph-building packages in Ti*k*Z with much more powerful options for this kind of graphics than the one offered by `circuitikz` poles, that are thought for a very different objective.

Comment: @Rmano Actually I used `tikzpicture`. Somehow when I pasted my codes, I forgot to delete the `circuitikz` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the manual, the size of the poles is defined by the `nodes width` key, which by default is 0.04. This number is a fraction of some "basic length". Change it with e.g. `\ctikzset{nodes width=0.2}`.

Below I used labels instead of adding extra nodes, but that's merely a suggestion.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{nodes width=0.2} % default = 0.04
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
                    \node (c) at (1.5,0) [ocirc, label=left:$c$] {};
                    \node (b) at (3,0) [ocirc, label=right:$b$] {};
                    \node (d) at (1.5,2) [ocirc, label=above:$d$] {};
                    \node (e) at (1.5,-2)[ocirc, label=below:$e$] {};
                    
                    
                    \path 
                    (a) edge           (d)
                    edge           (e)
                    (b) edge           (d)
                    edge           (e)
                    (d) edge           (c)
                    (c) edge           (e); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A couple of examples for how to apply this to just one diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \ctikzset{nodes width=0.2} 
         \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width=0.2]
         \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: But won't this change every pole used in my document? I want to change the size only for this particular diagram.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Move the `\ctikzset` to right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: You can also define `\tikzset{big ocirc/.style={ocirc, circuitikz/nodes width=0.2}}` and then use `node[big ocirc]{}` (not checked, but it should work).

Comment: Do I need to repeat `\begin{tikzpicture}
         \node (a) at (0,0) [ocirc, label=left:$a$] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}` several times as suggested in the answer by @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Of course not, that was just to demonstrate that the change was local to that diagram.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Sorry about the confusion, didn't think to clarify that ..

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Pretty nice solution you provided. Thanks!!